# Al momento de multiplicar por 100 en javascript me salen decimales

Tags: javascript

Cuando hago la multiplicación porque me sale esto ?

```js
  var x = 0.036*100;
   console.log(x); 
    
    //Deberia ser 3.6
```

Comment: Ve acostumbrándote. Casi todos los lenguajes de programación tienen esos "problemas". En aplicaciones más críticas a veces es mejor usar librerías que manejan ese inconveniente internamente. En este artículo hay una referencia sencilla https://es.quora.com/Por-qu%C3%A9-0-1-+-0-2-no-es-igual-a-0-3-en-la-mayor%C3%ADa-de-los-lenguajes-de-programaci%C3%B3n

Comment: @aeportugal esa no es la mejor respuesta posible.

Comment: No es una respuesta, es solo un comentario @Alfabravo

Comment: @aeportugal como comentario también es malo porque no es cierto. Pueden hacerse cálculos computacionales precisos y todo depende de cómo lo hagas. Acostumbrarse no es un comentario válido, constructivo ni real.

Comment: @Alfabravo creo que se refería a que se acostumbre a toparse con ese tipo de problemas. Lo cual es válido porque no hay lenguaje que se escape de la precisión aritmética. Representar números de coma flotante no es un paseo en el parque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que para llegar al resultado deseado deberias usar `.toFixed()`

```js
var x = (0.036*100).toFixed(1);
console.log(x);
```

Fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toFixed